# CakePHP Webroot .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

Normally one would have a webroot that looks like this:

```
/www/
  |
  +--index.php
  |
  +-- js/
  |   |
  |   +-- xyz.js
  |
  +-- css/
  |    |
  |    +--xyz.css
  |
  +---etc.....
```

With my setup, it is going to be most beneficial for me to move everything into a common subfolder, leaving the index.php of the Cake app in the root.  I.e:

```
/www/
  |
  +--index.php
  |
  |
  +-- resources
         |
         +-- js/
         |   |
         |   +-- xyz.js
         |
         +-- css/
         |    |
         |    +--xyz.css
         |
         +---etc.....
```

What is my .htaccess going to look like?

Comment: As an additional bonus... what would .htaccess look like if I also had a php app, such as wordpress, inside the "resources" or whatever I call it directory?

Comment: PS - I want the subdirectory to be transparent to the code within the directory (if, for example, there is .php or other server side codes)